# Ag-grid-angular How to capture click in column header

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

Is there a way to capture click event on header .

similar to rowClicked event on rows .

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ag-grid Angular How to get click events on Header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153589/ag-grid-angular-how-to-get-click-events-on-header)