# Ag-grid Angular How to get click events on Header?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

#### Is there any way to get notified of click events on ag-grid's header in Angular?

The `<ag-grid-angular>`-Component offers multiple events for clicks on cells (e.g. *cellDoubleClicked*). Those don't get triggered for header clicks and I was unable to find any events specific for header clicks.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410163/ag-grid-angular-how-to-capture-click-in-column-header) was already asked by someone else in the past and not answered, so I don't think, there's any built in way.

#### Why do I need this?

I'm working with another library to supply context menus for the application, but I want to differentiate between different context menus for headers and regular cells. So just listening to the default angular click event (on the whole grid component) doesn't help, because I need the clicked column/cell.

For reference I'm currently using ag-grid 15.0.0, but I also didn't find anything in the current documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be possible if you define the header component (see: [Header Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#angular-header-component)). In your template for the header component you can create a `div` element (or any other container element) and define the `(click)` event handler. This worked for me:

```
<div (click)='onHeaderClick($event)'>
  <p>Name</p>
</div>
```

(Of course you'd probably want to pass the header title in the parameters to the `agInit()` method, since you wouldn't want to create a separate header component for every header!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some investigation it seems, that when implementing a custom Header Component, there's no real fallback behavior. I'd have to implement and maintain sorting and styling myself and I'm not a fan of that.

Comment: @KeTr I agree that it's not ideal, but it doesn't look as daunting as you might think. Take a look at this Plunker ... the `header-component` appears to implement the features you need: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/1rHK9l

Answer (score 2):

You could basically listen to the "sortChanged" event, that ag-grid provides when you click on the default header.

Comment: Yes, and when in sortChanged, the event doesn't tell you which column, so call getSortModel() to get it.

Comment: And note that getSortModel() will have a null column every three click by default, so set the column sortingOrder to exclude 'no sort'