# Click event for group header on ag-grid angular

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-angular-grid in this I have group header and child columns also.
I want to know click event of that group header click.
below how I create header :

```
  {
            headerName: "<span id='performanceData'>Performance</span> <i class='fa fa-eye group-open-settings-button' aria-hidden='true' data-group='PerformanceData' ></i>",
            groupId: "PerformanceData",
            marryChildren: false,
            onCellValueChanged:event=>{
                console.log('trst');
            },
            children: [
                {
                    headerName: "Talent Decision",
                    headerTooltip: "Talent Decision",
```

on click   this i wants to open a popup.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate component for your custom group header. This can be done by implementing the `IHeaderGroupAngularComp` and using `headerGroupComponentFramework`, as stated on the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#header-group-component) for the Header Group component.

Here is a rough sketch on how you can get it done.

First and foremost, on your main component that is using ag-grid, we will need to bind the input properties for `frameworkComponents`, and import your custom header group component.

On the component.html,

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
  <!-- other properties -->
</ag-grid-angular>
```

On the component.ts, define the component which will be binded to your `frameworkComponents`, and for your custom header.

```
import { CustomHeaderGroupComponent } from '../custom-header-group-component/custom-header-group.component';

constructor() {
  this.frameworkComponents = {
    customHeaderGroupComponent: CustomHeaderGroupComponent,
  };

  this.columnDefs = [
    {
      headerGroupComponent: 'customHeaderGroupComponent',
      // other properties for your group header
    }

  ];
}
```

Do not forget to include your custom header group component on your module.ts too:

```
import { CustomHeaderGroupComponent } from "./custom-header-group-component/custom-header-group.component";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AgGridModule.withComponents(
            [
              CustomHeaderGroupComponent
            ]
        ),
        // other imports 
    ],
    declarations: [
      CustomHeaderGroupComponent,
     // other components
    ],
    // others
})
```

On your custom component.html template for the header group, you can then bind the `(click)` event to the header to it:

```
<div (click)="openPopup($event)"><span id='performanceData'>Performance</span> <i class='fa fa-eye group-open-settings-button' aria-hidden='true' data-group='PerformanceData' ></i></div>
```

And on your component.ts for the header group, you can define the `openPopup()` method:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IHeaderGroupAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { IHeaderGroupParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

.
.
.

export class CustomHeaderGroupComponent implements IHeaderGroupAngularComp {
  params: IHeaderGroupParams;

  agInit(params: IHeaderGroupParams) {
    this.params = params;
  }
  . 
  .
  openPopup() {
    // handle the rest to enable to opening of the popup
  }

}
```

The full working demo is actually available [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular-cli-example/tree/master/src/app), though it is a complete demo for all the features.